# How to release a array which is created inside a for loop in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have created an array inside a for loop and I am not able to release it. It shows memory leaks. Here is my code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < [magArr count]; i++)
{
   Magazine *magObj = [magArr objectAtIndex:i];
   NSMutableArray *myArray = [data readEditions:[magObj.magazineID intValue]:0];//returns a array
}
[myArray release]; // memory leaks (retain count to -1)
```

If I use auto release also, it showing memory leak. How to solve this leak?

Comment: Can you please post the content of readEditions? As a general rule, a method that doesn't contain new, init or copy in the name should return an autoreleased object. So based on that assumption you won't need to release anything in the bit of code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the array that is being returned from `readEditions` is not autoreleased, it violates the [**Object ownership policy**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB).

You should release the object inside the loop because it is being leaked after every iteration of the loop if `readEditions` returns an object with a retain count > 0.

You should return an autoreleased object from `readEditions` because the method name does not contain `alloc`, `new` or `copy`.

Then, if you want, you can `retain` the autoreleased object to keep it around.

Here's an example of how your loop would look like if `readEditions` returned an autoreleased object:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [magArr count]; i++)
{
   Magazine *magObj = [magArr objectAtIndex:i];
   NSMutableArray *myArray = [[data readEditions:[magObj.magazineID intValue]:0] retain];
   //do something with myArray...
   [myArray release];
}
```